# spacy en_core_web_trf makes jupyter lab crash

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am trying to load the en_core_web_trf in Jupyter Lab in os. Everytime when I run it, it just crash and restart the kernel. Could you tell me what is the problem?
Everything works fine in en_core_web_md

Many thanks in advance
[image: problem image]

Comment: Did you install both `spacy` and `spacy-transformers`? And did you set Jupyter to use GPU? Did you clear the ressources/environment before or do you already have the md model loaded and now try to load the trf on top? Generally loading a model can take a bit, especially with limited ressources and having too many models loaded can cause ressource problems.

Comment: @ewz93 I already installed spacy and spacy-transformers. I also restart the terminal and clear the environment before load it. It still has the same issue. 
I don't understand why I have to change my Jupyter to use GPU?

Comment: Don't paste screenshots of errors, please copy/paste the text. Without a detailed error it's hard to be sure what's going on but it sounds like maybe you have GPU configuration issues.

Comment: @polm23 Because the error just this text and without any code error. How to fix the GPU configuration issue?